# How can I compute the rolling mean of a column for a set period of time, using Pandas and groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

| Date | Jockey ID | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-12-2018 | 4340 | 1 |
| 25-11-2018 | 4340 | 5 |
| 19-12-2018 | 4340 | 10 |
| 01-01-2019 | 4340 | 3 |
| 18-10-2017 | 8443 | 1 |
| 18-02-2018 | 8443 | 6 |
| 12-05-2018 | 8443 | 7 |

I want to compute the rolling mean final position for each `Jockey ID` for the last 1000 days. I am looking for something like this:

| Date | Jockey ID | Position | Mean Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-12-2018 | 4340 | 1 | 1 (1/1) |
| 25-11-2018 | 4340 | 5 | 3 (1+5)/2 |
| 19-12-2018 | 4340 | 10 | 5.33 (1+5+10)/3 |
| 01-01-2019 | 4340 | 3 | 4.75 (1+5+10+3)/4 |
| 18-10-2017 | 8443 | 1 | 1 (1/1) |
| 18-02-2018 | 8443 | 6 | 3.5 (1+6)/2 |
| 12-05-2018 | 8443 | 7 | 4.66 (1+6+7)/3 |

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: (Second data table):    Position:5         Mean: 3 (1+5/2)   ... the mean is 3.5, not 3

Comment: @MaximilianFreitag - it is `(1+5)/6=3`

Comment: Table corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#here freq not raise error, but also not working
df['new'] = (df.set_index('Date')
               .groupby('Jockey ID', sort=False)['Position']
               .expanding(freq='1000D')
               .mean()
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
print (df)
        Date  Jockey ID  Position       new
0 2018-12-23       4340         1  1.000000
1 2018-11-25       4340         5  3.000000
2 2018-12-19       4340        10  5.333333
3 2019-01-01       4340         3  4.750000
4 2017-10-18       8443         1  1.000000
5 2018-02-18       8443         6  3.500000
6 2018-12-05       8443         7  4.666667
```

```
#for any freq same ouput
df['new'] = (df.set_index('Date')
               .groupby('Jockey ID', sort=False)['Position']
               .expanding(freq='30D')
               .mean()
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
        Date  Jockey ID  Position       new
0 2018-12-23       4340         1  1.000000
1 2018-11-25       4340         5  3.000000
2 2018-12-19       4340        10  5.333333
3 2019-01-01       4340         3  4.750000
4 2017-10-18       8443         1  1.000000
5 2018-02-18       8443         6  3.500000
6 2018-12-05       8443         7  4.666667

#here freq not raise error, but also not working same output like no freq
df['new'] = (df.set_index('Date')
               .groupby('Jockey ID', sort=False)['Position']
               .expanding()
               .mean()
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
        Date  Jockey ID  Position       new
0 2018-12-23       4340         1  1.000000
1 2018-11-25       4340         5  3.000000
2 2018-12-19       4340        10  5.333333
3 2019-01-01       4340         3  4.750000
4 2017-10-18       8443         1  1.000000
5 2018-02-18       8443         6  3.500000
6 2018-12-05       8443         7  4.666667
```

Possible solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['new'] = (df.set_index('Date')
               .groupby(['Jockey ID', pd.Grouper(freq='1000D')])['Position']
               .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
        Date  Jockey ID  Position       new
0 2018-12-23       4340         1  1.000000
1 2018-11-25       4340         5  3.000000
2 2018-12-19       4340        10  5.333333
3 2019-01-01       4340         3  4.750000
4 2017-10-18       8443         1  1.000000
5 2018-02-18       8443         6  3.500000
6 2018-12-05       8443         7  4.666667
```

Comment: `freq` or `min_periods`? I didn't see `freq` in the definition of `expanding`.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin - check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.18.1.html?highlight=groupby%20rolling#whatsnew-0181-deferred-ops)

Comment: it is groupby + expanding, not `Series` or `DataFrame` + expanding, so `freq` not failed (but should be)

Comment: Well, it failed but the `Grouper` solution worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @BogdanDoicin - ` but for a specific track, named "X"` Can you explain more?