# How can I compute the rolling mean of a column for a set period of time, using Pandas and groupby, given a specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985613/how-can-i-compute-the-rolling-mean-of-a-column-for-a-set-period-of-time-using-p), only with a new column, `Track`:

| Date | Jockey ID | Position | Track |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-12-2018 | 4340 | 1 | Sha Tin |
| 25-11-2018 | 4340 | 5 | Sha Tin |
| 19-12-2018 | 4340 | 10 | Happy Valley |
| 01-01-2019 | 4340 | 3 | Happy Valley |
| 18-10-2017 | 8443 | 1 | Sha Tin |
| 18-02-2018 | 8443 | 6 | Sha Tin |
| 12-05-2018 | 8443 | 7 | Happy Valley |

What I am looking for is a way to compute the rolling mean final position, in the last 1000 days, on a specifically on Sha Tin. The final result:

| Date | Jockey ID | Position | Track | Mean Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-12-2018 | 4340 | 1 | Sha Tin | 1 (1/1) |
| 25-11-2018 | 4340 | 5 | Sha Tin | 3 (1+5)/2 |
| 19-12-2018 | 4340 | 10 | Happy Valley |  |
| 01-01-2019 | 4340 | 3 | Happy Valley |  |
| 18-10-2017 | 8443 | 1 | Sha Tin | 1 (1/1) |
| 18-02-2018 | 8443 | 6 | Sha Tin | 3.5 (1+6)/2 |
| 12-05-2018 | 8443 | 7 | Happy Valley |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Track` column to `groupby`:

```
df['new'] = (df.set_index('Date')
               .groupby(['Jockey ID','Track', pd.Grouper(freq='1000D')])['Position']
               .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
```

If need filter is possible, but output is different, for not matched are `NaN`s:

```
mask = df['Track'].eq('Sha Tin')

df.loc[mask, 'new'] = (df[mask].set_index('Date')
               .groupby(['Jockey ID','Track', pd.Grouper(freq='1000D')])['Position']
               .transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())
               .to_numpy())
print (df)
```

Comment: I meant on a specific track like `Track==Sha Tin`. I only need the results for Sha Tin.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin - so why is output for `Happy Valley` ? Not understand sample output data.

Comment: Sorry! I had edited the question.